# Can't redirect to controller ,always getting 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am using `javaconfig` to set up this project, but I don't know where I a doing wrong. I open `localhost:8080`, it shows `"hello world "`, but when I open `localhost:8080/home`, or `localhost:8080/blog/home` it shows 404 not found. Debugger have no information about that.

1. ide: idea 2017
2. server :tomcat 9
3. os : mac 10.13
4. no web.xml only java config

Project Structure:
[image: structure]

> pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xvnyata</groupId>
  <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>blog Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--spring需要的aop支持-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.generator/mybatis-generator-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--日志注释删除删除清楚删掉-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0-beta0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/druid -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.baomidou/mybatis-plus -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-plus</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibeetl/beetl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibeetl</groupId>
      <artifactId>beetl</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibeetl</groupId>
      <artifactId>beetlsql</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>

    <finalName>blog</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Mybatis自动生成插件 -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

</project>

    enter code here

> BeeTemplateConfig



        package config;

    import org.beetl.ext.spring.BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration;
    import org.beetl.ext.spring.BeetlSpringViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

    @Configuration

    public class BeeTemplateConfig {

        @Bean(initMethod = "init")
        public BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration beetlConfig() {
            BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration beetlGroupUtilConfiguration = new BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration();
            // 如果需要配置 beetl 相关功能，就传入beetl的配置文件
            // 模板的位置就在 beetl.properties 中配置
            // 如 RESOURCE.root=/WEB-INF/templates/beetl/
            beetlGroupUtilConfiguration.setConfigFileResource(new ClassPathResource("/beetl.properties"));
            // 或简单的方式就是使用默认配置文件，用下面的代码设置模板位置
            //beetlGroupUtilConfiguration.setRoot("/WEB-INF/templates/beetl/");
            return beetlGroupUtilConfiguration;
        }

        @Bean
        public BeetlSpringViewResolver beetlViewResolver(BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration beetlConfig) {
            BeetlSpringViewResolver beetlSpringViewResolver = new BeetlSpringViewResolver();
            // 设置编码
            beetlSpringViewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            beetlSpringViewResolver.setSuffix(".btl");
            beetlSpringViewResolver.setConfig(beetlConfig);
            return beetlSpringViewResolver;
        }
    }
```

> RootConfig

```
    package config;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config","dao","service","controller"})
@Import(DruidDatabase.class)
public class RootConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator proxycreate(){
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator proxycreate = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        proxycreate.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        proxycreate.setBeanNames("*ServiceImpl");
        proxycreate.setInterceptorNames("transactionInterceptor");
        return proxycreate;
    }



}

enter code here
```

> WebAppInitializer

```
enter code here


  package config;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


import static org.aspectj.ajde.core.JavaOptions.CHARACTER_ENCODING;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        LOG.info("------root配置类初始化------");
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        LOG.info("------web配置类初始化------");
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        LOG.info("------映射根路径初始化------");
        return new String[]{ "/" };//请求路径映射，根路径
    }


}
enter code here
```

> WebConfig

```
package config;

import org.beetl.ext.spring.BeetlGroupUtilConfiguration;
import org.beetl.ext.spring.BeetlSpringViewResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    enter code here

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".btl");
        return resolver;
    }

    //静态资源的处理
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}

enter code here
```

Thanks for your answer.

> homeController

```
package controller;

import config.WebAppInitializer;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.beetl.core.Configuration;
import org.beetl.core.GroupTemplate;
import org.beetl.core.Template;
import org.beetl.core.resource.StringTemplateResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;


@Controller
public class homeController {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/console", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView park() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("redirect:/park/index.html");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mobile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView mobile() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("/mobile/login.btl");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/view/index.btl");
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code for `homeController`. This may be an issue with `RequestMapping`.

Comment: thanks,sunil ,neel fix my question title.
I have put the Controller (homeController) into post in the last.
please have a look my code,thanks @ShaneCoder